# Reigniting conditional statement after breaking out of it?

Tags: java, logic

I have a basic method which returns a string based on the input of a user:

```
public String getString() {

   String message = inputGenerator.getMessage(); // Returns user inputted string
   String messageStart = message.substring(0, 3); // Get start of message
   String concat = ""; // Variable to concatenate messages

   if(messageStart.equals("Hi")) {
      concat += message; // Append input to concat string.
      inputGenerator.getMessage(); // Call for another user prompt
   } else {
      concat += message; // Append input to concat string.
   }

  return concat; // Return concatenated string. 

}
```

**What I want to do:**

As you can hopefully work out, what I want to do is prompt a user for more messages if the start of the message includes the word `hi`, until it doesn't, and return that concatenated string, e.g.

```
>> Enter a string ("hiexample")
>> Enter a string ("hianotherexample")
>> Enter a string ("nothi")
>> returns "hiexamplehianotherexamplenothi"
```

**The problem**

The problem is that the if statement only works once because `inputGenerator.getMessage();` obviously jumps out of the conditional after being called.

If I try to use a `while()` statement instead, it runs forever and eventually crashes the program.

Comment: Show `while` loop you are trying to use.

Comment: can you show the logic you tried when using a while loop, and just an fyi: `"hi".equals("Hi") == false`

Comment: @PM77-1 while is just while(messageStart.equals("Hi"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems shorter and more elegant:

```
public String getString() {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    String read;

    do {
        read = inputGenerator.getMessage();
        msg.append(read); 
    } while (read.toLowerCase().startsWith("hi")); 

    return msg.toString(); 
}
```

I use the StringBuilder because it's more efficient than String concatenation like you do.
Let me explain:

```
concat += message;
```

gets inflated by the compiler to

```
concat = new StringBuilder(concat).append(message).toString();
```

Now guess which is more efficient. :)

Comment: This is a great bit of help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're thinking?

```
public String getString()
{
    String result = "";

    while (true)
    {
        String message = inputGenerator.getMessage();
        result += message;

        if (!message.startsWith("hi"))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I think you want `2` as the second argument to `substring` since your continuation string is `"hi"`, right?

EDITS: Several tweaks thanks to Floegipoky, clcto and StackOverflowException (see comments/other answers below).

Comment: You mean `if (!message.substring(0, 2).equals("hi"))` instead of `if (message.substring(0, 2) == "hi")`?

Comment: Pretty sure the OP can figure out those details... at least I hope so ;-) It's the control flow he was trying to figure out.

Comment: Nope, use `!message.substring(0,2).toLowerCase().equals("hi")`

Comment: @clcto: Or `equalsIgnoreCase`... Or `startsWith` and `toLowerCase`.